# Can't delete some Files JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I am writing a program to filter out rows of lines which contains zip-codes into corresponding separate zip files using threading. Since I'm dealing with millions of rows creating a new object of `OutputStream` and closing it each time wasn't feasible. Thus I created a Hash for each zip-code and kept on writing to it. After the completion of the code, I went through closing each Hash iteration closing each stream. 
The problem now is some files(varying in each run) still throw `AccessDeniedException`.

I also set `setWritable(true)` before trying to delete it which returns true also when i call `file.delete()` it returns true but the file isn't deleted.

Any help would be appretiated.

Used to write to File

```
private synchronized void write(String file, StringJoiner joiner) throws Exception {
    OutputStream out = zipOutStreamMap.get(file);
    if (out == null) {
        out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(file), CREATE, APPEND);
        zipOutStreamMap.put(zip, out);
    }
    out.write((joiner.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes());
    out.flush();
}
```

Used to close stream

```
for (Map.Entry<String, OutputStream> out : zipOutStreamMap.entrySet()) {
        try {
            if (out.getValue() != null) {
                out.getValue().close();
                File zipFile = new File(out.getKey());
                System.out.println(out.getKey() + " " + zipFile.setWritable(true));
                System.out.println(zipFile.delete());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Using thread as follows

```
try {
            Path file = Paths.get(inputProperty.inputFilePath);
            if (!(new File(outputPath)).exists()) {
                (new File(outputPath)).mkdir();
            }
            Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            for (String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator) {
                synchronized (this) {
                     pool.execute(new ZipWriter(line, inputProperty, outputPath));                      
                }
            }
            lines.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure some of your threads are not still writing to the files, while you are trying to close them?

Comment: I used `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` with `pool.shutdown()`,  `while (!pool.isTerminated()) {Thread.sleep(100);}`to check if pool was complete. Is it possible thread is running even of `pool` is terminated

Comment: That looks okay then. Although, you could use pool.awaitTermination() to wait for termination easily without using the while loop.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to delete the file in the same folder as when you created the file? Like this File zipFile = new File(out.getKey(), outputPath);

Comment: yep `zipOutStreamMap` contains the location in `String` and `OutputStream` as Map created earlier so its the same file.

Comment: Show your output/statcktrace